# What unusual property does this finite automata yield?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I'm asked to construct a finite automata for a given task. The Automata should accept the values `zero` or `one`. In the starting state its output is 1. The output doubles with every `one` as input and is split in half with every `zero` as input. The maximum value for the output is 4. Another `one` as input will put the automata in an *error-state* and it will stay there regardless of the input. An input of `zero` in the initial state will bring the automata in the error state as well.

I was able to construct this automate and give the transition table. It looks like this

```
State        Input     Subsequent State
I (001)      0         E (111)
I (001)      1         A (010)
A (010)      0         I (001)
A (010)      1         B (100)
B (100)      0         A (010)
B (100)      1         E (111)
E (111)      0         E (111)
E (111)      1         E (111)
```

The next short question asks

> What unusual property does this automata yield?

At this point I'm stuck. The only thing I notice, that the error state is kind of a fix point of the automate. Once the error state is reached it stays there regardless of the input. It this the wanted answer? I don't notice anything special in particular..

Comment: It appears to encode bit-shifting operations as binary

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ah, I see. It shifts three bit data with exactly one `1` to the left with each `one` as input, right? And shifts it to the right with each `zero` as input right? If the single `1` is shifted _over the edge_ it goes to the error state right?

Comment: Does the problem statement say how many error states there are to be? Does it specify that from any state with output 2, the state reached on input `zero` is the initial state? If not (say, reaching another state O with output 1), does it specify the behaviour on another `zero`?